# Given a Type, how do you determine what type it is boxed as?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, types, .net-4.0

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable?view=netframework-4.8):

> When a nullable type is boxed, the common language runtime automatically boxes the underlying value of the Nullable object, not the Nullable object itself...

In code:

```
public Type GetBoxedType(Type type)
{
    Type result;

    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null)
    {
        result = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    return result;
}
```

How could I generalize this method for all closed types?

Comment: have you looked at Generic Methods

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _"for all closed types"_...I mean, _reference_ types aren't boxed, so the method should probably the original type (or throw?). _Value_ types (except `Nullable<T>`)  will be boxed as the same type....and for `Nullable<T>` you already have an implementation. Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jawad - can you say some more?

Comment: @RenéVogt - the qualification of closed type simply means that this method will never be called with an open type (e.g. GetBoxedType(typeof(IList<>))).  I am trying to achieve a method that returns the right answer for any closed type =)  You response implies that there are only 3 cases:  value types (not including nullable), nullable types, reference types.  Does that cover all possible cases?

Comment: I know what a closed type is, but still the question doesn't make sense to me. Please give an example of which type you want to pass to the method and what you expect as result.

Comment: @RenéVogt - updated my prior comment.  The nature of creating a method is that I don't know the type ahead of time.  It could be any closed type passed into the  method.  For example, GetBoxedType(typeof(List<string>)) should return typeof(List<string>), whereas GetBoxedType(typeof(int?)) should return typeof(int).  I'm looking for a more complete solution that covers other possible boxing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this is what you want:

```
Type GetBoxedType(Type type)
{
    var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    return underlyingType ?? type;
}
```

For reference types it returns the same type (that is for `List<string>` it will return `List<string>`, because reference types are not boxed).
For value types other than `Nullable<T>` it will also return the same type (e.g. `int` for `int`), because that's how they are boxed.
And for `Nullable<T>` it will return `T` like you already implemented.

Comment: Is it possible to create a class that specifies how it's boxed?  If so then this solution wouldn't do the right thing in that case (if you are not forced to declare that somewhere, then maybe there's no generalized solution).  Also, you're saying that, for built-in .NET types, these are the only 3 cases?

Comment: @SFun28 A `class` will never be boxed. So you cannot specify _how_ it will be boxed. Boxing means to put a _value-type_ instance from stack/registers into heap. I would not say there are three cases. Classes aren't boxed at all, value types are all boxed the same way. There is only _one_ special case: `Nullable<T>` where the magic is happening that only the `T` is boxed instead of the whole `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant to say a custom struct.

Comment: But it seems you are rather thinking about casting/conversion here, but not boxing. Maybe if you add some context to your question about what you are actually trying to achieve we could give a more useful answer. Looks like an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/337882).

Comment: All good, I think this gets me 99% of the way there.  Can a custom struct specify how it's boxed?  If so I'd just have to solve for that case if it's even possible.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Boxing is a single IL command that simply puts the bits of your value-type on the heap. There's no way to change that process. Thatswhy I think you might want to cast/convert before boxing.

Comment: Thanks!  Then we have a 100% solution!  Accepted as the answer and upvoted.  It seems Nullable is the only "special case" in the framework.

Comment: Yes, there's no *how* in specifying how to box (in the language or IL) other than just learning how the CLR boxes.That said, you *can* layout your struct how you want in memory, but that's a different thing altogether from boxing. That's enough "hows" for me now.